# how to use the verb 'face'

Tags: transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

This is one of the questions from SAT.

Preserving rare and valuable books is one of the challenges facing the Librarian of Congress.

My question is if the sentence above has no error.
Isn't the verb 'face' a transitive in the sentence like "...one of the challenges the Librarian of Congress is facing"? 
or "...one of the challenges faced by the Librarian of Congress"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. When the LoC faces a *challenge*, the challenge *faces* back - the two are 'face to face'.

Comment: Yes. It's a Path [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf), usually reserved for humans (or human groups, like the LC); the experiencer/traveller "moves along a path to a goal", and of course _face_ means the part of humans that contains the sense organs and is oriented in the direction of forward motion. If you are moving in one direction and someone (perhaps a metaphoric "someone") blocks your path, your face and their face will be, um, _face to face_; they will _face_ you, and you will _face_ them. OK?

Comment: You can also rephrase the sentence any number of ways, but the gerund (facing) can remain.  E.g., "Facing the Librarian of Congress is a major challenge:  preserving rare and valuable books."  In fact, even though I changed the plural "challenges" to the singular "challenge", I like my version better (of course, I'm biased in my favor!).

Comment: &rhetorician: Do you use the term 'gerund' for **any** -ing form? - I'd have to call _facing_ in "...one of the challenges the Librarian of Congress is facing" a participle rather than a gerund. Though having read Quirk's article on the gradience of -ing forms, I think it's best to drop traditional terms as they are used ambiguously and sometimes illogically.